# Registration Page

Tags: multisite, user-registration, homepage

I've recently installed a wordpress network to my website and i'm stuck with a huge problem!
my default blog now redirects to the signup form automatically and not the blogs home page.

I have set the static page in the reading settings, and disabled registrations.

it still redirects to

domain.com/wp-signup.php?new=domain.com

and it should go just to domain.com

is there an easy way of stopping this from happening?

**Solved this**, all it is is a missing 
`define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'http://www.domain.com' );`
from wp-config.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this, all it is is a missing

```
define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'http://www.domain.com' );
```

from wp-config.php